# measurement unit in css for font size

Tags: css, fonts

I already searched and read SOF on this topic, I found some posts interesting, particularly one that suggested to use pt for font-size because it is neither related to the pixel density, nor to the resolution, but I'm still in search...

Is there any way so I could define a specific font size in my css document, but use it with proportion to the default font size of the browser? something like this:

x = default-font-size-of-browser %

unit-to-use = (x) / (my-target-size%) em

then use that for every padding, margin, etc. in the design, which is not possible in css as long as I know!

I've found people guessing like "usually, the default of browser is 16px font-size", I don't want to guess.

Some suggested to use 100% for html tag and define all other sizes with rem: now what if the user has a wrong font size as default of the browser? Then the user will see all sites that have that overwritten well, except my site, that is not overwriting it! Sure I can think of that as being the user's problem and leave it on, but I won't take that way.

Please give ideas.

Comment: It is up to you to decide what works for your sites. You've already listed several good options - try and pick one.

Comment: People do not have wrong font size as default of browser. The defaults in all browsers are sensible, and if the user changes that, it is because they need some other size. If you try to force that to something else, THEN the user will have wrong font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should not change the font size of body text. The user has configured his browser to suit his display and his eyesight. If you force the font size to something else, the user may not be able to read  the text.

Option to use **pt** as unit to define font size is meant to be used with **printers**, but it is not good idea to use it for screen. It tries to set absolute size ( 1pt=1/72in). Even if the text is correct size on your desktop PC, it is most likely not correct on a small phone screen. (A phone screen is viewed from shorter distance, so the font needs to be smaller.)
In addition to that, pt size depends on the dpi setting on users computer. Many users have wrong dpi setting (it depends on the monitor used), so the size of the font will not be what you expect.

The unit **px** is not good since the size of pixels wary between displays, as does users eyesight. However, it is useful if you want the text to be aligned correctly with an image, since the image (when displayed in actual size) is dimensioned as pixels.

In most cases, the size of body text should be 100% (i.e. do not change it). For other elements, use **relative** sizing (e.g. as **%**). If you *must* change the font size for body, the other elements will automatically change relative to that. The size given as % is size relative to the font size on parent element.

Answer (score 1):

The default font size is the same in every browser, AFAIK.

The common suggestion for font size is:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

This sets the base font size to 10px, but with scaling.

Then lets say for example you want the text of your website to be 16px, you do:

```
p, ul, ol, table {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

And then to set your headings:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 2.5em;
}
h2 {
   font-size: 2em;
}
```

For 25px and 20px respectively.

This method means that even if the default font size isn't as you would expect, the text should still scale accordingly.

See this [other post by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289198/css-how-can-i-adjust-my-font-size-fill-all-the-space-in-a-justified-layout) for some cool things you can do with fonts and font sizes. Works well with responsive layout

Comment: You should not set font size to 62,5%, because then the font size is only 62.5% of the size that the user wants it to be. It will be very small size and difficult to read.

Comment: Taken straight from this [Mozilla Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems): _"A popular technique to use throughout the document is to set the the font-size of the body to 62.5% (that is 62.5% of the default of 16px), which equates to 10px, or 0.625em. Now you can set the font-size for any elements using em units, with an easy-to-remember conversion, by dividing the px value by 10. This way 6px = 0.6em, 8px = 0.8em, 12px = 1.2em, 14px = 1.4em, 16px = 1.6em."_.

Comment: Not only that, I completely disagree with you. Hardly anyone will change the font-size of their browser, most wouldn't even know how to do it. Even of the 0.1% of people that have changed it, 99% of those will have increased the size because of their bad eyesight. Forcing all text to be at 100% (16px for 99.9% of people), would cause text to take up far more space on a page than is needed. Especially if said blind person has increased their size to 24px! If you're going to build something, build for the majority, not the minority.

Comment: I completely disagree with you. Only stupid people do not adjust their browser to suit their needs. And nobody has suggested to FORCE the font size to 100%. Forcing the font size is one of the top 10 mistakes in web design. The point is that you should NOT FORCE the font size, because then it is practically ALWAYS WRONG size.

Comment: In fact, your "force 100%" is logically ridiculous. 100% means that you DO NOT FORCE the size to be anything, but instead let it be the size user wants it to be. And 100% is NOT 16px, it highly depends on the browser, display resolution and user settings. Even if the user does not change the settings, 100% is not the same on desktop PC and phone screen.

Comment: I don't think the OP is tracking this any more, but you sir, are an idiot. You need to [stop coding like it's the 90's](http://koti.mbnet.fi/pkl/). [One does not simply let the end-user change the website design](http://i.imgur.com/jpgN45S.jpg).