# CSS styling of divs in or text in a dynamic clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have recently created a dynamic clock using php and javascript, I have also styled it to how I want it using php. I have the clock in 4 different divs. (Text, Date, Time, Day) My only query is using CSS how do I set the width of each of these divs (or maybe the text itself) to all have a width of 180px no matter what the time or date is. so the clock is perfectly square.

Here is My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLga4c37/5/) of how far I have got.

My code is also below

***HTML***

```
<div class="clock" id="day"></div>
<div class="clock" id="time"></div><div class="clock" id="hour"></div>
<div class="clock" id="date"></div>
```

***UPDATED css***

```
* {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.clock {
color:#bbb;
font-size: 44px;
}

#time {
display:inline-block;
letter-spacing:3px;
}
#hour {
margin-left:10px;
display:inline-block;
font-size:28px;
}
#date {
font-size:30px;
}
</style>
```

The idea I am going for you can see below. All the text has the same width.

[IMAGE OF WHAT I AM TRYING](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/CLOCK.jpg)

Comment: See this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289198/css-how-can-i-adjust-my-font-size-fill-all-the-space-in-a-justified-layout/)

Comment: Did you try to include a container to your elemnts and set width to desire pixels? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9p5do2q/)

Comment: Did you find your answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<div>` to wrap things together when you need it so they inherit their parent element's width.  Also, use spans to your advantage for their default 'inline' property.  This will shorten the css you need.

```
<div class="clock">
    <div id="day">Sunday</div>
    <div><span id="time">5:34</span><span id="hour">pm</span></div>
    <div id="date">Feb 28th</div>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
.clock {
    border:1px solid red;
    color:#bbb;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    min-height:180px;
    text-align:center;
    width:180px;
}
.clock > div{
}

#time {
    letter-spacing:3px;
}
#hour {
    padding-left:10px;
    font-size:28px;
}
#date {
    font-size:30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: spans default to inline, not inline-block last time I checked.

Comment: still thank you @FactoryAidan that gives me something to work with

Comment: I love this place. Thanks guys. I updated the answer to 'inline'.

Comment: but @JamieBarker I am using divs its not just <p> elements within one div, its seperate divs entirely

Comment: @LewisHasty I fail to see how that information is relevant to anything I've said on this thread? :S

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and taking the logic used in the linked question and answer in the comment I sent: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLga4c37/10/)

#### JS

```
function FontSizes() {
    var Width = $('#clock').width();
    $('.clock').each(function() {
        var NewFontChars = $(this).text().length;
        var NewFontSize = (Width / NewFontChars) * 1.95; // Apparently it's 2 characters per 100% width in px, make it just less so we have a bit of breathing room
        $(this).css('font-size', NewFontSize+'px');
    });   
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="clock">
    <div class="clock" id="day"></div>
    <div class="clock"> 
        <span id="time"></span> <span id="hour"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clock" id="date"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono);
#clock {
    background:#333;
    width:180px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Ubuntu Mono', Arial, sans-serif; 
    color:#bbb;
}
#time {
    display:inline-block;
}
#hour {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS EXAMPLE ONLY WHEN SECOND LINE IS LONGES:

```js
tday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
tmonth = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

function GetClock() {
    var d = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
    var dx = d.toGMTString();
    dx = dx.substr(0, dx.length - 3);
    d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
    d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 0);
    var nday = d.getDay(),
        nmonth = d.getMonth(),
        ndate = d.getDate(),
        nyear = d.getYear(),
        nhour = d.getHours(),
        nmin = d.getMinutes(),
        nsec = d.getSeconds(),
        ap;

    if (nhour == 0) {
        ap = " AM";
        nhour = 12;
    } else if (nhour < 12) {
        ap = " AM";
    } else if (nhour == 12) {
        ap = " PM";
    } else if (nhour > 12) {
        ap = " PM";
        nhour -= 12;
    }

    if (nyear < 1000) nyear += 1900;
    if (nmin <= 9) nmin = "0" + nmin;
    if (nsec <= 9) nsec = "0" + nsec;

   document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = "" + tday[nday].toUpperCase() + "";
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "" + nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec + "";
    document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = "" + ap + "";
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = "" + tmonth[nmonth].toUpperCase() + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear + "";
}

window.onload = function () {
    GetClock();
    setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
    
    var day = $('#day').width();
    var time = $('#time').width() + $('#hour').width() + 10;
    var date = $('#date').width();
    
    if(date > day && date > time){
     alert('date');
        
    }else if (time > day && time > date){
        var lengthDay = $('#day').html().length-1;
        var differenceDay = time-day;
        var letterDay = differenceDay / lengthDay;
        
        var lengthDate = $('#date').html().length-1;
        var differenceDate = time-date;
        var letterDate = differenceDate / lengthDate;
        
        $('#day').css({'letter-spacing':letterDay});
        $('#date').css({'letter-spacing':letterDate});

    }else{
     alert('day');
    }
    
}
```

```css
.clock {
  font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
  color:#bbb;
  font-size: 44px;
}
#day{
  display:inline-block;
}
#time {
  display:inline-block;
  letter-spacing:3px;
}
#hour {
  margin-left:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
}
#date {
  font-size:30px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock" id="day"></div><br>
<div class="clock" id="time"></div>
<div class="clock" id="hour"></div><br>
<div class="clock" id="date"></div>
```

---

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLga4c37/6/)