# How to determine largest possible font-size such that it fits on one line in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag `wrapper` with **adjustable dimensions**.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <p class="inside-text">Some text</p>
</div>
```

In this setup, how do I set the **font-size** of `inside-text` to be as big as possible, such that it fits on one line (fitting) using CSS?

Comment: Have you tried? http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: @Pangloss preferably no jQuery

Comment: You can't do it without Javascript, though, which means you'll have to manually caculate average letter width. And even then it's fairly unpredictable, but you can approximate it that way. @RazvanBalosin Theres a typographical difference between letter-spacing and font-size (and I am not talking about style attributes here).

Comment: There are jQuery free versions if you take a look of this page - https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js#dont-use-jquery

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289198/css-how-can-i-adjust-my-font-size-fill-all-the-space-in-a-justified-layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that (AFAIK) you cannot accomplish that using only CSS.

A common CSS technique for adjusting `font-size` to achieve a pleasing text layout in responsive design is the media query. Just wait until the text breaks at a certain width, and add another media query. Such fun!

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 330px) {
    .inside-text { font-size: 1.1em; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .inside-text { font-size: 1.3em; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .inside-text { font-size: 1.5em; }
}
```

Like Pangloss mentioned in the comments above, biting the bullet and using a javascript library such as [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com) is an alternative option.

Answer (score 3):

Just playing: if you know in advance the length of your text (e.g. "some text" = `9`) you could try this tricky but pure-CSS solution (tested on Chrome/Firefox, try to resize the output frame)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVvWEW

**HTML**

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: calc(100vw / .625 / 9);
}
```

Comment: Not bad at all... what is the .625?